# background color using core graphics

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have the following code in my drawRect:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

I basically wanted to set the background of this view to be red.. however the code above doesn't do it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer by @PaulPerry is a good one. But if you want help with the existing code you should post the complete `drawRect:` method of your `UIView` based class. Update your question with the full method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

`CGContextFillPath` fills a "path," which you'd have to first build with a series of other calls, like `CGContextAddRect` and `CGContextAddArc`. It's easier just to fill the rect.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way to change the background color of a view is:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Or if you are in the view controller:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
CGContextRef ref= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextFillRect(ref, self.bounds);
```